# DISLIN is not working on Code Blocks

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, codeblocks

I am using:

-IDE: Code Blocks 13.12

-C language

-Cygwin64 Compiler (http://www.cygwin.com/)

-Dislin Distribution for Cygwin: dl_11_gc (http://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin/win-64-bit)

-Windows 7 OS

I have been trying to make DISLIN graphic library works on Code Blocks, the problem is that, even thougth I have added the correct path to the search directories I am always getting these kind of errors:

```
        undefined reference to `metafl'
        undefined reference to `scrmod'
        ...
```

These functions are used in the first example code that is provided in this link:[enter link description here](http://www.mps.mpg.de/1757268/exa_c#section_1)

Apparently my Code Blocks project was able to find the "dislin.h" file, but I want to know what cause this kind of errors, do I am missing something?.

Comment: have you followed `readme.cyg` ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to add the library files (with extension  *.a) and the library path to those files.